# Why is the auto-vectorized version of this program fragment slower than the simple version

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, vectorization

In a larger numerical computation, I have to perform the trivial task of summing up the products of the elements of two vectors. Since this task needs to be done very often, I tried to make use of the auto vectorization capabilities of my compiler (VC2015). I introduced a temporary vector, where the products are saved in in a first loop and then performed the summation in a second loop. Optimization was set to full and fast code was preferred. This way, the first loop got vectorized by the compiler (I know this from the compiler output).

The result was surprising. The vectorized code performed 3 times slower on my machine (core i5-4570 3.20 GHz) than the simple code. Could anybody explain why and what might improve the performance? I've put both versions of the algorithm fragment into a minimal running example, which I used myself for testing:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Prepare timer
    LARGE_INTEGER freq,c_start,c_stop;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

    int size = 20000000; // size of data
    double v = 0;

    // Some data vectors. The data inside doesn't matter
    vector<double> vv(size);
    vector<double> tt(size);
    vector<float> dd(size);

    // Put random values into the vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tt[i] = rand();
        dd[i] = rand();
    }

    // The simple version of the algorithm fragment
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c_start); // start timer
    for (int p = 0; p < size; p++)
    {
        v += tt[p] * dd[p];
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c_stop); // Stop timer

    cout << "Simple version took: " << ((double)(c_stop.QuadPart - c_start.QuadPart)) / ((double)freq.QuadPart) << " s" << endl;
    cout << v << endl; // We use v once. This avoids its calculation to be optimized away.

    // The version that is auto-vectorized

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tt[i] = rand();
        dd[i] = rand();
    }

    v = 0;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c_start); // start timer
    for (int p = 0; p < size; p++) // This loop is vectorized according to compiler output
    {
        vv[p] = tt[p] * dd[p];
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < size; p++)
    {
        v += vv[p];
    }
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&c_stop); // Stop timer

    cout << "Vectorized version took: " << ((double)(c_stop.QuadPart - c_start.QuadPart)) / ((double)freq.QuadPart) << " s" << endl;
    cout << v << endl; // We use v once. This avoids its calculation to be optimized away.

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added a large amount of work by storing the products in a temporary vector.

For such a simple computation on large data, the CPU time that you expect to save by vectorization doesn't matter.  Only memory references matter.

You added memory references, so it runs slower.

I would have expected the compiler to optimize the original version of that loop.  I doubt the optimization would affect the execution time (because it is dominated by memory access regardless).  But it should be visible in the generated code.  If you wanted to hand optimize code like that, a temporary vector is always the wrong way to go.  The right direction is the following (for simplicity, I assumed `size` is even):

```
for (int p = 0; p < size; p+=2)
{
    v += tt[p] * dd[p];
    v1 += tt[p+1] * dd[p+1];
}
v += v1;
```

Note that your data is large enough and operation simple enough, that **NO** optimization should be able to improve on the simplest version.  That includes my sample hand optimization.  But I assume your test is not exactly representative of what you are really trying to do or understand.  So with smaller data or a more complicated operation, the approach I showed may help.

Also notice my version relies on addition being commutative. For real numbers, addition is commutative.  But in floating point, it isn't.  The answer is likely to be different by an amount too tiny for you to care.  But that is data dependent.  If you have large values of opposite sign in odd/even positions canceling each other early in the original sequence, then by segregating the even and odd positions my "optimization" would totally destroy the answer.  (Of course, the opposite can also be true.  For example, if all the even positions were tiny and the odds included large values canceling each other, then the original sequence produced garbage and the changed sequence would be more correct).

Comment: If vectorization can be done at all, it can use multiple accumulators.  But yes, multiple accumulators will produce slightly different rounding from usual auto-vectorization.  It's too bad compilers are bad at using multiple accumulators, because they're essential for saturating the FP hardware.  e.g. Intel Haswell has 5c latency FMA, with one per 0.5c throughput.  So you need 10 vector accumulators to keep 10 FMAs in flight to saturate its FMA units.

Comment: Your version might let a compiler vectorize with one accumulator even without `-ffast-math`, though (for double precision, with one vector holding two 64b doubles).